# Is there a word, phrase or idiom saying the opposite of a fair-weather friend?

Tags: phrases, idioms, antonyms

As a noun or adjective. For example as in the sentence: He proved to be a fair-weather (antonym?) friend.

Comment: ***true friend***

Comment: The question is unclear. Which kind of antonym? Someone who is a friend in all kinds of situations (weather)? Someone who is a friend only when things are going badly (bad weather)? Someone who is an enemy when things are going well (fair weather)? Something else? Unclear.

Comment: steadfast friend, friend through thick and thin

Answer (score 1):

Not so common but ***all-weather*** friend is used in this sense.

Urban Dictionary:

> **[all-weather friend](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=all-weather%20friend)**
>   A friend who helps you every time. Either in a happiness or sorrowfulness.
>   China and Nepal are all-weather friends. Both countries help to each other in each and every different
>   situations.

Answer (score 0):

A friend in need is a friend indeed